# Big problem Android Studio 3.3 Canary 11 (gradle 3.3.0 alpha 11) with Kotlin 1.3.0-rc-57 and constraintlayout 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I config Android Studio 3.3 Canary 11 (gradle 3.3.0 alpha 11) with Kotlin 1.3.0-rc-57 and `constraintlayout 2.0`

I have some problems like this, and AS can not work with some projects, i.e https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/

Problem: AS can't understand Kotlin code, no auto-complete of codes, etc.....

Not all projects, maybe only the projects with `constraintlayout 2.0`

Error in AS:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.io.IOException: File format error reading /Users/xxxxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/constraintlayout-2.0.0-alpha2.aar/66d32464c2b8004a7b95f523ebd1e95c/R.txt line 1743: 'int[] styleable GradientColor { 0x0101020b, 0x010101a2, 0x010101a3, 0x0101019e, 0x01010512, 0x01010513, 0x010101a4, 0x0101019d, 0x01010510, 0x01010511, 0x01010201, 0x010101a1 }'
    at com.android.utils.concurrency.CacheUtils.getAndUnwrap(CacheUtils.kt:37)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectLightResourceClassService.getAarRClasses(ProjectLightResourceClassService.kt:172)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectLightResourceClassService.getAarRClasses$default(ProjectLightResourceClassService.kt:169)
    at com.android.tools.idea.res.ProjectLightResourceClassService.getLightRClassesAccessibleFromModule(ProjectLightResourceClassService.kt:122)
```

[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116402286)

Comment: Did you try same with  stable version of Android Studio?

Comment: @Khemraj no, however, some people said, it works even @ AS 3.2.1 which is beta. So, it should work @ stable version. The problem could only @ AS 3.3 .

Answer (score 0):

same problem with:

- AS version:3.3 canary12,
- kotlin version:1.2.61,
- constraintlayout version:2.0.0-alpha2

downgrade constraintLayout to 1.1.3

it's works

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this when migrating to AndroidX. Go through **ALL** of your dependencies and make sure the version numbers are correct. I had a few that on the support lib had a higher version number than the latest AndroidX. This caused the IDE to basically crap itself.

You can check for all the versions at:
1. Material libray - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
2. AndroidX - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx